# liferay content management system and use as external content source

Tags: content-management-system, liferay-6

I want to use liferay as web content management system. 
In my case I want to upload images on liferay and want to access those uploaded images through my program.
I am new to liferay.
can anyone please guide me or suggest any link through which I can full fill this requirement.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to "site Administration" > "Content" > "Document and Media" > add files there and then copy the url from an input (when you click on an file)

specify which liferay version you are using

Comment: I am using liferay 6.2 EE version

Comment: and one more thing can I just specify the image name and use some utility so that I don't need to hard code the whole URL???

Comment: ok here an exmaple : if this is the url ( picture file is test.gif ) http://localhost:9090/documents/11642/0/test.gif/605efd43-eef0-45dc-8d87-384729365393?t=1409579347981
you can use : /documents/11642/0/test.gif it should work (if you re still confused what s you URL ? )

Comment: if it's the right answer please set it as the right one :D

Comment: I am using http://localhost:8080/webdev/guest/document_library/imageTitle I want to use only foldername/imageTitle in my code can I do that. If its possible how can I use.

Comment: No ! You should use /documents/11642/0/imageTitle.. 
Please display the whole url ..

Comment: hi thanks for the reply I am able to access the image. there is one more thing I want to ask is can you help me a bit about saml assertion or saml plugin custom field in liferay PORTAL Thanks in advance

Comment: i am able to add the custom field but i am not able to pick that value from LDAP..:( please help me out if it doesn't bother your work

Comment: Im sorry I'm not familiar with the SAML .. Wish I can help !