# How to show images uploaded in to liferay portal in another html page (another domain)

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay, liferay-6

I want to display one image from liferay portal in my HTML5 mobile application. Due to authentication i cannot able add image url directly as src for img tag. i tried ajax request with authentication. but its not working.

```
$.ajax({
    url : Imgurl,
    method : 'GET',
    headers : { Authorization : authValue },
    success:function(data){
            $("#image").attr("src","data:image/png;base64,"+data);
            //alert("ok");
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("err");
    }
});
```

image url like this

```
rootUtl + "/documents/12323/91975/portalName/6ce91660-36d1-4b6d-982e-1c1d92079c7b?version=2.0&t=1429436062610"
```

Any option to show images from liferay portal (from documents folder, with authentication , not public) in anothe html page. in my case its HTML5 Mobile application. from liferay JSON API am getting image url and its correct. how to load that image in my html page.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968895/liferay-content-management-system-and-use-as-external-content-source

Comment: am getting image url from json api dynamicaly., is thr ay way to download that image with auth header using ajax